# Richtextbox tab and newline

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I don't know if anyone has this problem or is just me, since I couldn't find anything on the web.
In a richtextbox if I start a line with 'tab' (any amount of them), when I press enter, the new line starts at the same postion as the one before.
What I want is the new line to start at the beginning of the line.
Here's an example of what is happening:

```
     My first line starts here, then I press enter
     My second line starts here
```

This is what I want:

```
    My first line starts here
My second line starts here
```

Is there a way to solve this by changing a property, or do I have to do it inside the code?
Thanks :)

Comment: No repro.  Post code that demonstrates this behavior.

Comment: Well I can reproduce it...just set AcceptsTab to true and this is what happens.  Don't know if there's an easy way to stop it though...my guess is that it's something to do with the FlowDocument that contains all the text?

Comment: You're right lanR. That's how I got this issue. Funny thing though, if I press backspace in the new line, containing one or more tab's (that came from the previous line) it eliminates it. Maybe it has to do how Flow Document handles the new line command by copying previous tabs to the new one.... :(